# Updating a state inside a React function

Tags: reactjs, state

Is it possible to update the react state inside a function, and see the results in other components?

The example below is an App.js in a create-react-app file. I want to update the content of the h1 tags when I edit the textarea. I've simplified the example as far as I can.

Only newData3 and newData4 reflect the content of the textarea.

newData1 and newData2 only render "this.newData1() =" and "newData2="

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data:'AA',
    newData: 'AA AA'
    }
  newData1=()=>{this.state.data + " " + this.state.data}
  render() {
    const newData2=()=>{this.state.data + " " + this.state.data}
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>this.newData1() = {this.newData1()}</h1>
        <h1>newData2={newData2()}</h1>
        <h1>newData3={this.state.data + " " + this.state.data}</h1>
        <h1>newData4={this.state.newData}</h1>
      <textarea 
      value={this.state.data} 
      onChange={(e) => {
        this.setState({data:e.target.value}) ;
        this.setState({newData:e.target.value + ' ' + e.target.value})
      }}
        /> 
</div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write like this. Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ywzoq8oqmx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) { // Set state initial value in constructor function
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          data: 'AA',
          newData: 'AA AA'
        }
      }
      newData1() { return (this.state.data + " " + this.state.data) } // This can use arrow funtion, but still need return
      render() {
        const newData2 = () => { return (this.state.data + " " + this.state.data) } // this need return
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>newData1={this.newData1()}</h1>
            <h1>newData2={newData2()}</h1>
            <h1>newData3={this.state.data + " " + this.state.data}</h1>
            <h1>newData4={this.state.newData}</h1>
            <textarea
              value={this.state.data}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ data: e.target.value });
                this.setState({ newData: e.target.value + ' ' + e.target.value })
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the brackets of newData1 and newData2 to make implicit the return statement:

`newData1 = () => this.state.data + " " + this.state.data`

and

`const newData2 = () => this.state.data + " " + this.state.data`

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible. In onChange of textArea call function like below. Keep in mind that when you declare a function inside the component you need to do either bind the function in constructor or use an arrow function like

Below code uses Arrow function:

```
  handleTextArea = e => {
      this.setState({data:e.target.value, newData:e.target.value + ' ' + e.target.value
      });
 }

   <textarea value={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleTextArea} />
```

Below code uses regular function with binding In constructor

```
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.handleRextArea = this.handleTextArea.bind(this);
     }

     handleTextArea(e) {
      this.setState({data:e.target.value, newData:e.target.value + ' ' + e.target.value
      });
 }

   <textarea value={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleTextArea} />
```

And in render when call other component just pass state value as props to the component and access the props value in other component in h1 tag like

```
      render(){
         <div>
             <textarea value={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleTextArea} /> 
              <OtherComponent data={this.state.data} />
         </div>
      }
```

Now in Other component display data like

```
     <h1>{this.props.data}</h1>
```

Please not you should always bind function in constructor only but not anywhere else in the component. Also no need to see multiple setStates to update two different values instead use single setState as I mentioned in my code

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/042j0lwn0

So the answer to your question Yes you can use the components state to render the result in other components. You were already close!
You didn't correctly implement the newData1 and newData2 functions.
I have made your code slightly better by adding some small changes:

- Used setstate once
- Destructured your state values
- stored your target.value in a const
- showed you how to use arrow function inside render()
- showed you how to use newData1 as class Method

Good luck! :)

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: "AA",
          newData: "AA AA"
        };
      }

      // method definition
      newData1() {
        return this.state.data + " " + this.state.data;
      }

      render() {
        // please desturucture!
        const {
          state: { data, newData }
        } = this;

        // arrow function
        const newData2 = () => data + " " + data;

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>this.newData1() = {this.newData1()}</h1>
            <h1>newData2={newData2()}</h1>
            <h1>newData3={data + " " + data}</h1>
            <h1>newData4={newData}</h1>
            <textarea
              value={data}
              onChange={e => {
                // store the value in a const
                const value = e.target.value;

                // use setState once and use the ... to make a shallow copy
                this.setState({
                  ...this.state,
                  data: value,
                  newData: value + " " + value
                });
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```